# How to store multidimensional array with Ormlite in Sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm storing an `Item` in an in-memory Sqlite datastore using Ormlite's `Db.Insert(item)`. The resulting array is `null`. Do I need to change the way I'm storing it or the way I'm retrieving it?

```
public class Item
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int[,] Numbers { get; set; }
}

public class Tester {

    void Test() {
        var item = new Item() { Numbers = new int[5,5] };

        item.Numbers[1,1] = 1234;

        using (var db = new ....) {

            db.Insert(item);

            var Id = db.LastInsertedId();

            var result = db.SingleById<Item>(Id);

            /*
            OUTPUT: 

             result.Numbers == null                                                  

            */
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays aren't supported in ServiceStack, i.e. in OrmLite or its text Serializers.

Comment: So how do I store it? Wrap it in another class then blob it?

Comment: Yeah, use a different data structure.